# c++ How to make argument based commands

Tags: c++

Hi im currently working on a practice code for my game. The game is going to be a command based game and you can type commands to do certain things. For example, if you type; "Math Add 1 2" it would add 1 and 2. Or if you did; "Math sub 10 5" it would give you 5. This is what i have came up with so far...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

static string Input; //Define Input

int main() {
    cout << "Command ";
    getline(cin, Input);
    if (Input.find("help")) { // Checks If string contains "help"
        if (Input.find("math")){ cout << "\n The math command can be used to do mathimatic equations."; } //if string contains help check if it also contains "math"
        if (Input.find("exit")){ cout << "\n Exits Program."; }
    }

    cin.get();

    return 0; //End Of Main
}
```

Here would be a possible outcome:

```
Command help Math
The Math command can be used to do mathimatic equations
```

Thanks in advance i am going to be going into sleep mode i will be back tomorrow XD

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Are you familiar with `switch`?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Bernhard yes i am familiar with a switch but it wouldn't be what i was looking for, because a switch would look for exactly what i typed, so if i wanted to make a command like; "math add 10 5" it would add 10 and 5. That couldn't be tested for in a switch. Unless you can look for part of a string with switch then that would work also.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that functionality by creating pure virtual class `CommandHandler` for example and every command should be derived from it. And with it you should create `CommandEngine` for registering all your handlers in it and finnaly feed arguments of command line to it.

Here is example:

```
class CommandHandler
{
    virtual string& const GetCommandName() const = 0;
    virtual void run(const std::vector<string>& argumentList /* or char*[] */) const = 0;
}

/*
This class should parse command line to find and execute appropriate command handler. Of course we should register handlers here before parsing.
*/

class CommandEngine
{
    CommandEngine();
    //Should add handler into array/vector or even better map.
    void registerHandler(CommandHandler handler);
    /* This function should pick first word as command name, find appropriate handler and execute it with remaining arguments*/

    void run(std::vector& const arguments /* or char*[] */);
}

class AddHandler : public CommandHandler
{
   //Implement CommandHandler interface
   ...
}

void main(...argc, argv...)
{
    CommandEngine engine;
    engine.register(AddHandler);
    ....
    engine.run(argv);
}
```